# Unable to boot an HP DL380 G5 running RHEL

Tags: redhat, storage-area-network, boot, lvm, hp-proliant

I have an HP DL380 G5 that was in a production network as a database server, with HP StorageWorks 2012fc / MSA 2000 SMB storage.  The production system has been brought down and the servers are now in my office.  I need to recover the DB to some historical data but am unable to boot the database box.

**Here's what is happening:**

I have connected the DL380 to the SAN switch and the SAN switch to the storage arrays.  When I boot into RHEL the boot screen stops at the line:

```
[ 3.254102] SELinux: initialized (dev usbfs, type usbfs), uses genfs_contexts
```

Then the box just sits there...

**Here's what I've tried:**

I used an ubuntu live cd to boot and tried to look around for a mount point to mount the drives and see if I can find anything... I can find and mount `/boot` under `/dev/csiss/c0d0p1` but I cannot find the `/` mount.  Using FDisk I found that `/` has a file system of type `Linux LVM`.  From thre I did some looking around the web and found that you [can't just mount a Linux LVM](http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/Mounting_a_Linux_LVM_volume.html) -- but I don't have a `/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00` or such (which is what the grub configuration uses for the root mount point.

And that is about the extent of my SysEng experience/knowledge...

*anyone know what else I can try to get this box up and running with or without the SAN (I have a dump of the DB that I can load on the local volume if I can get to the config)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have now managed to install the LVM via a package on USB in the Ubuntu live CD.  Using that we removed the fstab entry for the attached storage and were able to boot the RHEL install.

So I answer my own question 30 minutes after asking it.